# xamarin ios formatting a TextLabel in a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, xamarin

is there any reason why I cant use string.format to format a TextLabel in a UITableViewCell

there are no errors but in seems to ignore or compress my padding  eg {0,-10}

I am using xamarin studio for ipad development and was hoping to use format rather than creating a custom cell

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by using "string.format to format a TextLabel". Do you have some sample code you can share to show how you are doing it?

Comment: Basically in the code snippet below the string padding is not being properly observed:-            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);            
cell.TextLabel.Text = string.Format ("{0,-10}   {1,-20} {2,50} ", tableItems [indexPath.Row].JobId, tableItems [indexPath.Row].Name, "NEW");

Comment: Relying on whitespace for formatting, particularly with a proportional font, rarely works.  Look at using NSAttributedString instead (http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/text_field/style_text/)